# How to do a natbib citation within the suffix to another citation?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I need to do this using natbib:

> (McFadden 1978, Ben-Akiva and Lerman 1985, but see Bruch and Mare 2012 for an accessible introduction).

My current attempt at it:

```
  \citep[][but see \citep[][for an accessible introduction]{bruch_methodological_2012}]{mcfadden_modeling_1978,ben-akiva_discrete_1985}.
```

Which results in an ugly error:

```
BibTeX I didn't find a database entry for "["
```

Is there any way of defining that suffix that includes a citation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with an additional set of `{}` around the inner `\cite`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{angenendt,
  author       = {Angenendt, Arnold},
  title        = {In Honore Salvatoris~-- Vom Sinn und Unsinn der
                  Patrozinienkunde},
  journaltitle = {Revue d'Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique},
  date         = 2002,
  volume       = 97,
  pages        = {431--456, 791--823},
  langid       = {german},
  indextitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
  shorttitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
  annotation   = {A German article in a French journal. Apart from that, a
                  typical \texttt{article} entry. Note the \texttt{indextitle}
                  field},
}

@article{baez,
  author       = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},
  title        = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra {V}: 2-Groups},
  journaltitle = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  date         = 2004,
  volume       = 12,
  pages        = {423-491},
  version      = 3,
  eprint       = {math/0307200v3},
  eprinttype   = {arxiv},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  annotation   = {An \texttt{article} with \texttt{eprint} and
                  \texttt{eprinttype} fields. Note that the arXiv reference is
                  transformed into a clickable link if \texttt{hyperref} support
                  has been enabled.  Compare \texttt{baez\slash online}, which
                  is the same item given as an \texttt{online} entry},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep[][but see {\citep[][for an accessible introduction]{baez}}]{angenendt}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```